# Which header defines the macro that specifies the machine architecture?

Tags: linux, header-file

*Shorter version of question:*

Which C header contains the macro that corresponds to the machine architecture of the system (e.g., `__x86_64__`, `__ia64__`, `__mips__`?)

*Longer version of question:*

I'd like to run the [ganglia](http://ganglia.info/) monitoring tools on a [Tilera](http://tilera.com/)-based system that runs Linux.

Ganglia doesn't currently have support for Tilera. To get this to work, I ned to modify a C function called [machine_type_func](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ganglia/browser/trunk/monitor-core/libmetrics/linux/metrics.c#L523) that returns the machine architecture. The body of this function is determined at compile-time, it looks like this:

```
g_val_t
machine_type_func ( void )
{
   g_val_t val;

#ifdef __i386__
   snprintf(val.str, MAX_G_STRING_SIZE, "x86");
#endif
#ifdef __x86_64__
   snprintf(val.str, MAX_G_STRING_SIZE, "x86_64");
#endif
...
   return val;
}
```

I need to add the appropriate line for Tilera, but I don't know the name of the macro that specifies a Tilera-based system. I'm guessing this macro is defined in one of the standard Linux headers, but I don't know which one to look in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No header file defines it - those macros are predefined by the compiler. To find out the full list of predefined macros do this:

```
echo | gcc -E -dM -
```

Then look through the results for likely macros.

Answer (score 2):

More precisely, I think this is where the `__x86_64__` is defined for example: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases%2Fgcc-10.2.0/gcc/config/i386/i386-c.c#L688

```
 cpp_define (parse_in, "__x86_64__");
```

but I didn't have the patience to modify the source, recompile and test it out yet. A good way to search is:

```
git grep '"__aarch64__'
```